# How to get only the construct signature of a class?

Tags: typescript, constructor

I'd like to get the type of a TypeScript `class` constructor function. In my simple attempts it is always generic `Function` and not the actual constructor with the parameters as I'd expect.

```js
class BufferedController {
  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id
  }

  static defaultBufferSize = 100 as const

  id: number
}

// ?? Just generic Function not the actual constructor
type instanceConstructor = BufferedController["constructor"]

// Class type
type C = typeof BufferedController

// This works fine to get other static properties from the class
type n = C["defaultBufferSize"]
// ?? Also generic Function not the actual constructor
type c = C["constructor"]
```

What is the correct way to get the type of the constructor function from the `class`? I'd like to end up with a type like `constructor(id: number) => BufferedController`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Could you add the type you want so the question is more clear? Preferably like `I expect it to be of type ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got what you want. We'll write a type that gets ONLY the construct signature like this:

```
type CtorType<T> = T extends { new (...args: infer Args): infer Ret } ? { new (...args: Args): Ret } : never;
```

A class constructor certainly extends just a construct signature, so we take the arguments and inferred return type and create a new construct signature.

It's the same construct signature in the class constructor except it doesn't have anything else like static members.

Then we can use it like this:

```
declare const ctor: CtorType<typeof BufferedController>;

ctor.defaultBufferSize // error - doesnt exist

new ctor(0);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=13#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCuAzRBTATigJgYQPYDsAXNXEEdaAbwFgAoaaYAiY+YQ3NACgEtMAuaPngBbAEboAlFToMGhABY8IAOj7QAvND6zoAXzq6WYQj2DRMKRGHghCCZOgDKPAF4pN0AIwAGH9EhGZkJDem0BIVEJNDoDWjpCAE8ABw9sDjQAFRSUAB5MgD5PTOgUAA9CFHxMGEohFAB3aC4VVrA0AHMIQR58VDRoAEFOiEkevooAJRRCfWgAfip6ppa2kcFhrrHoadm9aEF8FAA3dABuUMtQdo8mfBZGDMF0zmzU3KTU3EQ4JH6sPBEEhkdAFC7xWjsTgqSzWWz2P7ONwoUJHJpQ7g+SRnIA)

Disclaimer: this does not work for overloaded constructors.

```
type CtorType<T> = T extends { new (...args: infer Args): infer Ret } ? { new (...args: Args): Ret } : never;

type T = CtorType<{
  new (a: number): string;
  new (b: string): number;
}>;

// type T = new (b: string) => number;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwsD2AnAKuCAeZA+KBeKyUEAHsBAHYAmAzlAN5TkQDuUAFAHRcCGiA5tQBcUAJbkAZhERQAgv2oBKYWMnSAShGBQAvlAD89Ri3ZcOvAcLkClUDVt3CmANykBuALAAoL6EgE8sAgoaOh0XlBGrGzcjgCuALYARlI21MCIYnwenhFMUYnCaRnkfDbkCcmI2dpYrkA)